# How to extract xml from xml.gz?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, gzip

I'm using a Windows 10 computer and I have a file that I want to use in a Java application. Let's call the file example.xml.gz. I want to convert it to an XML file so I can view the data in Eclipse, but I can't figure out how to extract the data. Do I unzip it, if so how?

Comment: .gz is gzip compression

Comment: Thank you. Do I use gunzip example.xml.gz in the cmd?

Answer (score 1):

Open gitbash and in the dir where the xml.gz file is located use:

gunzip example.xml.gz

then the XML file will be extracted and you can open the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can gunzip a file in Java with this simple method:

```
public static void gunzip(Path fin, Path fout) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("GUNZIP "+fin+" -> "+fout);
    try(final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(fout);
        final InputStream in   = new GZIPInputStream(Files.newInputStream(fin))) {
        in.transferTo(out);
    }
}
```